# Reading from child console pipe hanging under some conditions

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, console-application

In my Win32 program I implemented executing a console application and reading its std/err output. Basically it's the same code as given in MSDN: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So far, so good. It worked like a charm, reading both std and err streams with all my console applications. But obviously (due to the global HANDLE variables) the code is designed to run console applications one by one, never together. So I've changed it a bit:

- The global `HANDLE` variables replaced with the local ones. They are passed into the helper functions.
- A parameter named `bWait` added. If it's `false`, no reading from the console pipe after starting and no waiting for a process handle (a flavor of asynchrony).
- Instead, the reading handles are returned to a caller (thru given pointers). They can be used for reading from the pipe later.

Why do I need this? I want to start *tshark* (a console version of *Wireshark*, a traffic sniffer) with `bWait = false`, then start my own utility with `bWait = true` and wait until my utility stops working. Then I want to check, whether my utility pings a server. (Since we have a lot of utilities, this would be important functionality of our auto-testing procedure). So, I'd like to read from the *tshark* console pipe after that and parse its log.

Here is my modifications:

```
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes
//  for STDERR and STDOUT.
PROCESS_INFORMATION CreateChildProcess(HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Wr, HANDLE     hChildStd_ERR_Wr,
const std::wstring& cmd, bool& bSuccess, DWORD& exitCode, DWORD& lastError, bool bWait = true)
{
// Set the text I want to run
//char szCmdline[]="test --log_level=all --report_level=detailed";


    bSuccess = false;

    wchar_t wrBuffer[BUFSIZE];
    ::wcscpy_s(wrBuffer, cmd.c_str());

    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDERR and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        wrBuffer,      // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        0,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo) != 0;  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        lastError = ::GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        lastError = 0;
    }

    if (bWait && bSuccess && ::WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
    {
        bSuccess = false;
    }

    if (bWait && FALSE == ::GetExitCodeProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess, &exitCode))
    {
        bSuccess = false;
    }

    if (bWait)
    {
        ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_ERR_Wr);
        ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    }

    return piProcInfo;
}

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
void ReadFromPipe(HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE hChildStd_ERR_Rd, std::wstring& stdS, std::wstring& errS)
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    bool bSuccess = FALSE;
    std::string out = "", err = "";
    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL) != 0;
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        std::string s(chBuf, dwRead);
        out += s;
    }
    dwRead = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hChildStd_ERR_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL) != 0;
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        std::string s(chBuf, dwRead);
        err += s;
    }

    wchar_t utf[10000] = { 0 };

    ::MultiByteToWideChar(866, 0, (LPCCH) out.c_str(), -1, utf, sizeof(utf));
    stdS = utf;
    StringReplace(stdS, std::wstring(L"\n"), std::wstring(L"\r\n"));

    ::MultiByteToWideChar(866, 0, (LPCCH) err.c_str(), -1, utf, sizeof(utf));
    errS = utf;
    StringReplace(errS, std::wstring(L"\n"), std::wstring(L"\r\n"));
}

bool ExecuteCmd(std::wstring cmd, std::wstring& std, std::wstring& err, std::wstring& code, DWORD& lastError,
                bool bWait = true, HANDLE* phChildStd_OUT_Rd = nullptr, HANDLE* phChildStd_ERR_Rd = nullptr)
{
    HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_ERR_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hChildStd_ERR_Wr = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDERR. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &hChildStd_ERR_Wr, &sa, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDERR is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_ERR_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create the child process.
    bool bSuccess = false;
    DWORD dwExitCode = 9999;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo = CreateChildProcess(hChildStd_OUT_Wr, hChildStd_ERR_Wr, cmd, bSuccess, dwExitCode, lastError, bWait);

    if (phChildStd_OUT_Rd)
        *phChildStd_OUT_Rd = hChildStd_OUT_Rd;
    if (phChildStd_ERR_Rd)
        *phChildStd_ERR_Rd = hChildStd_ERR_Rd;

    if (!bWait)
        return true;

    wchar_t buffer[10] = { 0 };
    code = ::_itow((int) dwExitCode, buffer, 10);

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process.
    ReadFromPipe(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, hChildStd_ERR_Rd, std, err);
    ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
    ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_ERR_Rd);

    return true;
}
```

Now, the problem. When I tried starting *tshark* in the no-waiting mode, reading from pipe hanged up. Namely, in `ReadFile`.

```
if (g_iConnection != -1 && g_Products[i].PingbackDomain.size() > 0)
    {
        wchar_t buf[5] = { 0 };
        std::wstring list, err, code;
        DWORD dwErr = 0;
        std::wstring cmd = L"C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark -a duration:5 -l -i ";
        cmd += ::_itow(g_iConnection + 1, buf, 10);
        cmd += L" -f \"host ";
        cmd += g_Products[i].PingbackDomain;
        cmd += L"\"";
        ExecuteCmd(cmd, list, err, code, dwErr, false, &hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_ERR_Rd);
        ::Sleep(500);
    }
...
// Starting my utility (if this section is commented out, ReadFile still hangs).
...
if (hChildStd_OUT_Rd && hChildStd_ERR_Rd)
{
    std::wstring traffic, tsharkErr;
    ReadFromPipe(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, hChildStd_ERR_Rd, traffic, tsharkErr);
    ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
    ::CloseHandle(hChildStd_ERR_Rd);

    if (tsharkErr.size() > 0)
    {
        std::wstring msg = L"There has been an issue, while logging with Wireshark:\r\n\r\n";
        msg += tsharkErr;
        ::MessageBox(NULL, msg.c_str(), L"uhelper", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    else if (traffic.length() > 0)
    {
        newOutput += L"\r\nTraffic to ";
        newOutput += g_Products[i].PingbackDomain;
        newOutput += L":\r\n";
        newOutput += traffic;

        if (newOutput[newOutput.length() - 1] != L'\n')
            newOutput += L"\r\n";
    }
}
```

Did I break the MSDN code with my modifications? Unfortunately, I can't find how (and where).

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem (before creating a process!):

```
if (!bWait)
    {
        DWORD mode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT;
        ::SetNamedPipeHandleState(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &mode, NULL, NULL);
        ::SetNamedPipeHandleState(hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &mode, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

After applying `PIPE_NOWAIT` reading stopped hanging.